# My Indian passport's first page is a little damaged. Is it going to be a problem?

Tags: passports, india

[image]

As you can see only the seal page is a little damaged. Other than that my booklet is in perfect condition. Do I have to apply for a new passport or would this be usable?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That is clearly a damaged passport, even the government seal is damaged. Forget everything else.

**It is not a good idea to use it anymore**. Luckily it is not damaged beyond recognition, it will be relatively easier to replace it.

> **Q6:  My passport booklet is damaged. I want to go abroad on urgent basis. What should I do?**
>
> A: In case your passport has not been damaged beyond recognition, i.e. passport number is legible, name is legible and photo is intact, then you can apply for re-issue of passport under the Tatkaal scheme. But, if passport has been damaged beyond recognition, then you cannot apply under the Tatkaal scheme. In that case, you need to visit Passport Officer at your nearest Passport Seva Kendra to get the passport on urgent basis.

[Passport India: Lost/Damaged Passports](https://portal2.passportindia.gov.in/AppOnlineProject/online/faqLostDamagedPassports)

Comment: It's damaged alright, but I doubt you would be refused entry over it, since the damage affects neither the ID page nor any visas.  Getting a replacement if you have time is still a good idea though.

Comment: Their website doesn't list any levels of damage except 2 broad categories and this falls in the first one. So ill consider it liable to be replaced but obviously there are so many countries in the world there can't be a blanket yes or no answer to this question unless the OP mentions which country they are traveling to.